# Conditional sum contigous columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to sum the total time allocated per task. Time has been provided either in minutes or in hours.
[image: screen shoot]

For example Task A should be:
 30 minutes + 2 hours x 60 minutes/hour + 150 minutes = 300

What formula should I use on B2 to get such a result, considering that I have many more than 4 people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=sumproduct(n(C2:I2)*if(D2:J2="minutes",1,60))
```

[image]